# How to configure to use D-Link DSL-2750E as second router

Tags: router, internet

Problem: many users on my network (often streaming video) use up a lot of the bandwidth of my network.

Since yesterday I have new service provider who gave me new ZTE router. It handles the incoming internet fiber connection.

I would like to use my old DSL-2750E as a second router, creating a second network that also uses the internet from the ZTE router. The second network will handle most file transfers between PCs and would/should have no bandwidth problem from other users.

I have a network cable between ZTE router and Devolo Dlan 200 AVeasy . I have a second Devolo Dlan 200 AVeasy near to the D-Link DSL-2750E.

Questions:

1. Can the network cable between ZTE router and Devolo Dlan 200 AVeasy be plugged in any of the LAN ports?
2. Should the network cable between the Devolo Dlan 200 AVeasy and the D-Link DSL-2750E be plugged in port 4 or another port?
3. How should I configure the D-Link DSL-2750E?

Comment: Its worth considering how does having a second router actually solve your bandwidth problems, and how you want to set it up. Can you limit useage per interface on the ZTE or are the (presumably slower than your upstream) Devolo units going to end up being an intentional bottleneck? Do you actually want two network segments (in which case you need to use the WAN port on the dlink) or a single network segment (lan port + turning off DHCP)...

Comment: The idea is that my PCs are connected to the second network. File transfer between PCs can then use the full available bandwidth of the second router. If I want to access internet on the second router, the speed will be limited by the internet users on the first network. Am I correct in this assumption?